# API data into Array?

Tags: php, arrays, facebook-graph-api

How to combine all the results into an array? An array that will look like that:

array(fan_page1, fan_page2,...)

```
$likes = $facebook->api("/me/likes?");
foreach($likes['data'] as $like2){
echo $like2["name"],"<br/>";            
}
```

Code above gives me only table, like:

fan_page1

fan_page2

Answer (score 1):

[array_map](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) can be used to transform elements of an array.

```
function map_data($value) {
    return $value['name'];
};

$likes = $facebook->api("/me/likes?");
$data = array_map("map_data", $likes['data']);
```